# Erro na execução do Eclipse

Tags: java

Baixei o Eclipse, instalei e realizei todo o procedimento corretamente. Assim que terminei de instalar e reiniciar o PC, fui executar o programa e apareceu este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Eclipse não abriu.

Comment: Você tem o *JRE* e *SDK* instalado?

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve instalar o `JDK`do java disponivel [aqui](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt) fique atento na arquitetura (x86, x64), ela deve ser igual a do seu `sistema operacional` e igual a do `eclipse`, esta instalação irá altomaticamente adicionar o caminho do `JDK` e `JRE` ao `PATH`, o eclipse não terá problemas em encontrar e usar ambos.